# Is there a quick and easy way to create a checksum from Ruby's basic data structures?

Tags: ruby, hash, checksum

I have a data structure (`Hash`) that looks something like this:

```
{
    foo: "Test string",
    bar: [475934759, 5619827847]
}
```

I'm trying to create a checksum from that `Hash` to check for equality in the future. I tried using the `hash` method of the `Hash`, which resulted in a satisfyingly nice-looking hash, but it turns out that the same `Hash` will produce a different hash after the interpreter has been restarted.

I really just want to be able to create a ~128 bit checksum from a `Hash`, `String` or `Array` instance.

Is this possible?

Comment: If internal ordering of the hash or array is important then it's not a simple operation.  If internal order is unimportant, is there any reason you can't just take a Digest of the json or yaml content?

Comment: @mcfinnigan: Ordering of an array would be important, but not the ordering of a hash. I'll Google Digest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could calculate your own hash based on the object's [Marshal dump](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Marshal.html) or [JSON](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) representation.

This calculates the MD5 hash of a Marshal dump:

```
require 'digest/md5'

hash = {
  foo: "Test string",
  bar: [475934759, 5619827847]
}

Marshal::dump(hash)
#=> "\x04\b{\a:\bfooI\"\x10Test string\x06:\x06ET:\bbar[\ai\x04'0^\x1Cl+\b\x87\xC4\xF7N\x01\x00"

Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(hash))
#=> "1b6308abdd8f5f6290e2825a078a1a02"
```

**Update**

You can implement your own strategy, although I would not recommend to change core functionality:

```
class Hash
  def _dump(depth)
    # this doesn't cause a recursion because sort returns an array
    Marshal::dump(self.sort, depth)
  end

  def self._load(marshaled_hash)
    Hash[Marshal::load(marshaled_hash)]
  end
end

Marshal::dump({foo:1, bar:2})
#=> "\x04\bu:\tHash\e\x04\b[\a[\a:\bbari\a[\a:\bfooi\x06"

Marshal::dump({bar:2, foo:1})
#=> "\x04\bu:\tHash\e\x04\b[\a[\a:\bbari\a[\a:\bfooi\x06"

Marshal::load(Marshal::dump({foo:1, bar:2}))
#=> {:bar=>2, :foo=>1}
```

Comment: This is called *genious*,who knows core and stnd lib of Ruby in and out... Thank you Stefan...:)

Comment: This is almost exactly what I'm looking for. The only issue I see is that `{foo: "bar", meow: 123}` and `{meow: 123, foo: "bar"}` will produce different hashes even though I would consider them identical. Any ideas on what to do about that?

Comment: one option would be to extract the key/value pairs from the hash, ordered alphabetically by key, into an array, then hexdigest that array.

Comment: @Codemonkey why are your hashes ordered in different ways?

Comment: @Stefan: The point is that order isn't important in hashes, so different internal orders in two hashes shouldn't mean they produce different checksums.

Comment: In current Ruby versions hashes *are* ordered, it's not just an implementation detail. Just make sure their keys are inserted in the same order each time or simply sort them.

Comment: @Codemonkey updated my answer with an example for a custom strategy using `Hash#sort`

Answer (score 3):

To build on @Stefan's answer above, if order of the hash is important, sort the output before pushing it through Mashall.

```
require 'digest/md5'

hash = {
  'foo'=> "Test string",
  'bar'=> [475934759, 5619827847]
}

puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(hash.collect{|k,v| [k,v]}.sort{|a,b| a[0] <=> b[0]})) 
# 8509c564c0ae8dcb6c2b9b564ba6a03f

hash = {
  'bar'=> [475934759, 5619827847],
  'foo'=> "Test string"
}

puts Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal::dump(hash.collect{|k,v| [k,v]}.sort{|a,b| a[0] <=> b[0]})) 
# 8509c564c0ae8dcb6c2b9b564ba6a03f
```

Comment: Instead of `hash.collect{|k,v| [k,v]}.sort{|a,b| a[0] <=> b[0]}`, couldn't you just do `hash.sort`?

Comment: @Codemonkey interesting, it seems to do the same thing.  Try it :-)

Comment: Still though, this isn't an ultimate solution since a hash could contain other hashes whose orders are different. I don't think `Digest` or `JSON` is the answer. At least not unless I make a recursive function.

Comment: Sort is not a solution in general case: `{:a => 1, "b" => 2}.sort #=> ArgumentError`

Comment: Neither the `collect/sort` solution to sort the hash is generally valid: `('a' <=> :b) == nil`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate the checksum for the content of the hash, whatever the order of the data, using Marshal or sort or other techniques won't work.

The only solid way I found so far is the following:

```
require 'digest/md5'

hash1 = { "a" => 1, "b" => "2", c: { d: "3" } }
hash2 = { c: { d: "3" }, "a" => 1, "b" => "2" }

Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal.dump(hash1)) # => "5def3b2cbdddd3aa6730b6d0527c2d79"
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal.dump(hash2)) # => "8155698ccfb05b8db01490e9b9634fd9"

Digest::MD5.hexdigest(hash1.to_s.chars.sort.join) # => "812bb65d65380fc1e620a9596806cc35"
Digest::MD5.hexdigest(hash2.to_s.chars.sort.join) # => "812bb65d65380fc1e620a9596806cc35"
```

Comment: `{"a" => "b"}` and `{"b" => "a"}` would test as identical in this case

Comment: That's the point, hence my comment `whatever the order of the data` :)

Comment: Oh my bad, I misread your comment. You're right, that's an important drawback indeed :/ So no silver bullet I suppose :( Only a deep-sort would do the trick I guess :(